# How to restart the numeration of the keys in a object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, key

> What is the problem :

this are my data stored in  `this.state.jsondata` :

```js
{
  label{0:1,1:1}
  prediction{0:0,1:1}
  text{0:"abc",1:"def"}
}
```

This comes front `JSON.stringify(this.state.jsondata)` :

```
{"label":{"1":0,"2":0,"3":0,"4":0},"text":{"1":"aa","2":"bb,"3":"cc","4":"dd"},"prediction":{"1":2,"2":2,"3":2,"4":2}}
```

when I delete one element using this code :

```js
    removeData = (keyToRemove) => {
        // create a deep copy of the object
        const clonedJsonData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.jsondata))
        // now mutate this cloned object directly
        Object.keys(clonedJsonData).forEach(key => delete clonedJsonData[key][keyToRemove])
        // set the state
        this.state.jsondata = clonedJsonData
```

`this.state.jsondata` becomes :

```js
{
  label{1:1}
  prediction{1:1}
  text{1:"def"}
}
```

instead of starting back to 0 like :

```js
{
 label{0:1}
 prediction{0:1}
 text{0:"def"}
}
```

So basically I want to set the  `key` back to "0, 1, 2, 3.."

> What have I tried :

I tried to iterate through my data but there is something wrong in it with the way I loop through it :

```
    removeData = (keyToRemove) => {
        // create a deep copy of the object
        const clonedJsonData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.jsondata))
        // now mutate this cloned object directly
        Object.keys(clonedJsonData).forEach(key => delete clonedJsonData[key][keyToRemove])
        // reset keys value
        let i = 0
        Object.keys(clonedJsonData).forEach(function(key) {
            Object.keys(clonedJsonData[key]).forEach(function(k) {
                var newkey = i++;
                clonedJsonData[key][k] = clonedJsonData[key][k];
                delete clonedJsonData[key][k];
            })
        })
        // set the state
        this.state.jsondata = clonedJsonData
        
    }
```

> What is the expected output ?

The expected output is :

```
{
 label{0:1}
 prediction{0:1}
 text{0:"def"}
}
```

Comment: @evolutionxbox I don't think so

Comment: What you have stored is not JSON. Please show the real data/objects.

Comment: @Teemu this is my data https://imgur.com/a/epMQCfe

Comment: The expected output doesn't look valid?

Comment: Add it to the post as text ... What comes to the question, the keys of the object are not "autoindexed" like array indices are, as the keys are always strings.

Comment: @Teemu it's pretty much the same as the first example of `this.state.jsondata`.

Comment: This comes front `JSON.stringify(this.state.jsondata)` : `{"label":{"1":0,"2":0,"3":0,"4":0},"text":{"1":"aa","2":"bb,"3":"cc","4":"dd"},"prediction":{"1":2,"2":2,"3":2,"4":2}}`

Comment: This is ridiculous, why it's so hard to fix the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your key basically represents the index of the value, why not using an array?
{ label: [1,1], prediction: [0,1], text: ["abc","def"] }

If you now delete the first entry in each array, data.text[0] will be "def" and so on...

Edit:

If you don't want to convert the data, you gotta be carefull, especially if you parse and stringify the whole thing around and then loop over the keys. They don't have to be in the same order afterwards.

Instead of cloning the object, deleting the key you want to remove and then updating all keys, you could also copy the object manually and leaving the key to remove out

```
var data = {label: {0:0, 1:0}, prediction: {0:0, 1:1}, text: {0:'abc',1:'def'}};
console.log("Original Data");
console.log(data);

removeData = (data, keyToRemove) => {
    var ret = {};
    Object.keys(data).forEach(key=>{
        ret[key] = {};
        let idx = 0;
    
        for (let dataIdx = 0; dataIdx < Object.keys(data[key]).length; dataIdx++) {
            if (dataIdx.toString() !== keyToRemove) {
                ret[key][idx.toString()] = data[key][dataIdx.toString()];
                idx++;
          }
        }
    }); 
  
  return ret;
}

var reducedData = removeData(data,"0");
console.log("Reduced Data");
console.log(reducedData);
```

Note that I don't loop over the keys, so I don't get the order mixed up.
Note that I also removed the side effects from your original function by handing over the data object as parameter.

Comment: I'd like not to convert it

Answer (score 0):

So that's how I made it

```
    removeData = (keyToRemove) => {
        // create a deep copy of the object
        const clonedJsonData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.jsondata))
        // now mutate this cloned object directly
        Object.keys(clonedJsonData).forEach(key => delete clonedJsonData[key][keyToRemove])
        // reset keys value 
        let i = 0
        Object.keys(clonedJsonData).forEach(function eachKey(key) {
            i = 0
            Object.keys(clonedJsonData[key]).forEach(function eachKey(kkey) {
                var newkey = i++;
                clonedJsonData[key][newkey] = clonedJsonData[key][kkey];
                
            });
            delete clonedJsonData[key][i];
        });
        
        // set the state
        this.state.jsondata = clonedJsonData
}
```